# User ip's are not getting logged

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have 2 files on my site `config.php` and `log_user_ips.php`.

I am having trouble inserting user IP data into my database.

My DB contains `IPS` table.

**config.php**:

```
<?php require_once("path/to/base/ip_user_logs.php");  fSaveIPUserLog(); ?>
```

**ip_user_logs.php**:

```
<?php
function fSaveIPUserLog() {
    return;

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ips WHERE ip = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0):
        $check_fetched = mysql_fetch_array($check);
        $id = (int)$check_fetched['id'];
    else:
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ips SET ip = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $id = (int)mysql_insert_id();
    endif;
    mysql_free_result($check);

    mysql_query("UPDATE ips SET 
        times = times + 1, 
        host = '".mysql_real_escape_string(gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))."', 
        agent = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])."', 
        script = CONCAT(script, '".mysql_real_escape_string("\n".date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].((count($_GET))? '?'.http_build_query($_GET): ''))."'), 
        username = IF('".mysql_escape_string($_SESSION[SESSION_PREFIX.'user']['username'])."' != '', '".mysql_escape_string($_SESSION[SESSION_PREFIX.'user']['username'])."', username), 
        date = NOW() 
        WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

    return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say your file is `log_user_ips.php`, but you include `ip_user_logs.php`... Is that the problem?

Also you have a `return` statement directly after the definition of `fSaveIPUserLog()`, so that function won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, I have realized that I messed up the file names in this post, my actual structure is correct ip_user_logs.php.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a return statement immediately after the definition of your `fSaveIPUserLog()` function. This will exit the function before any of your other code in the function body will run.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return;` statement that wont run your `function fSaveIPUserLog()` you are also using. Also its now encouraged to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) not mysql.